# How to process mach formatted, imputed genotyes (ENIGMA) with plink

Tags: bioinformatics, genome

I have received genotypes of SNPs in dosage format, which have been imputed using the ENIGMA protocol. I want to analyse this data using [plink --dosage [...] --fam [...]](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/dosage.shtml) (which I believe is the right syntax.)

For each chromosome, I have received a tar-file consisting of the following files

```
% tar -tf chromosome.21.tar
chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.dose.gz
chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.erate.gz
chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.hapDose.gz
chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.haps.gz
chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.info.draft
chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.info.gz
chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.prob.gz
chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.rec.gz
```

None of these files seem to comply to the specifications of a dosage file as mentioned on the [plink's website](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/dosage.shtml). (In particular, not .dose.gz, as I would have guessed)

Does anyone have experience with this? Do I need to modify any of these files in any way?

---

```
% plink --dosage $dose --fam $fam
PLINK v1.90b3.38 64-bit (7 Jun 2016)       https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2
(C) 2005-2016 Shaun Purcell, Christopher Chang   GNU General Public License v3
Logging to plink.log.
Options in effect:
  --dosage /home/moebius/tmp/chromosome.21/chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.dose.gz
  --fam hammer.fam

32054 MB RAM detected; reserving 16027 MB for main workspace.
842 people (324 males, 518 females) loaded from .fam.
842 phenotype values loaded from .fam.
Using 1 thread.
842 people pass filters and QC.
Phenotype data is quantitative.
--dosage: Reading from
/home/moebius/tmp/chromosome.21/chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.dose.gz.
Error: Column 1 of
/home/moebius/tmp/chromosome.21/chunk1-ready4mach.21.imputed.dose.gz's header
isn't 'SNP'.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the program [dose2plink](https://www.genepi.qimr.edu.au/staff/sarahMe/dose2plink.html) to convert the ENIGMA dataset, which is in MACH format into PLINK dosage format.

Example:

```
./dose2plink.pl -dose chunk1.21.imputed.dose.gz -info chunk1.21.imputed.info.gz -out chunk1.21
```

which will produce `chunk1.21.pfam` and `chunk1.21.pdat.gz`.